# updating and filtering laravel datatable

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, laravel, datatables

I want to return a datatable which contains a collection in an array, I can see from the network inspector of my browser the responses and preview tabs, all the data is shown there but for some reason the table comes up empty, if I try returning the datatable inside the foreach loop only one result is returned but shows up on the table

I have two questions,

1. how do I get the data I have to show on the datatable.
2. how do I filter the data by date when thee date inputs are filled and thee filter button is clicked

this is the function that brings the orders to the page

```
  public function anyData(){
        
        $orders = Order::simplePaginate(10);
        foreach ($orders as $order){
      
            $id = $order->purchaser_id;
            $user = \App\Models\User::where('id', '=', $id)->first();
            $user_category = \App\Models\UserCategory::where('user_id', $id)->value('category_id');
            $category = \App\Models\Category::where('id', $user_category)->value('name');
            $referrer = \App\Models\User::where('id', '=', $user->referred_by)->first();
            $order_item = \App\Models\OrderItem::where('order_id', $order->id)->first();
            $quantity = $order_item->qantity;
            $product = \App\Models\Product::where('id', $order_item->product_id)->first();
            $price = $product->price;
            $order_total = $price * $quantity;
            
            if ($referrer) {
                $referred_distributors = \App\Models\User::where('referred_by', $referrer->id)
                    ->where('enrolled_date', '<', $order->order_date)
                    ->count();
            
                if ($referred_distributors < 5) {
                    $percentage = 5;
                } elseif ($referred_distributors >= 5 && $referred_distributors <= 10) {
                    $percentage = 10;
                } elseif ($referred_distributors >= 11 && $referred_distributors <= 20) {
                    $percentage = 15;
                } elseif ($referred_distributors >= 21 && $referred_distributors <= 30) {
                    $percentage = 20;
                } elseif ($referred_distributors >= 31) {
                    $percentage = 30;
                }
              
            }else{
                $referred_distributors = '0';
                $percentage = '0';
            }

            $datas[] = collect([
                ['order' => $order],
                ['user' => $user],
                ['referrer' => $referrer],
                ['referred_distributors' => $referred_distributors],
                ['percentage' => $percentage],
                ['commision' => ($percentage * $order_total)],
               
            ]);
            
        }

      
        return app('datatables')->collection($datas)
                ->addIndexColumn()
                ->addColumn('action', function($row){
                    $actionBtn = '<a href="#invoice" class="invoice more" data-toggle="modal"
                    data-target="#invoice" data-id="$order->id">View Item</a>';
                    return $actionBtn;
                })
                ->rawColumns(['action'])
                ->make(true);
      
     
        

       // return Datatables::of(User::query())->make(true);
    }
```

this the table which displays the data which is currently working fine

```
  <table class="table table-bordered" id="users-table">
                            <div class="col-md-3 mb-5">
                                <h2>Date from</h2>
                                <input type="date" class="form-control" id="min" name="min"
                                    data-date-split-input="true">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3 mb-5">
                                <h2>Date to</h2>
                                <input type="date" class="form-control" id="max" name="max"
                                    data-date-split-input="true">
                            </div>

                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col">Invoice</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Purchaser</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Distributor</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Referred Distributors</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Order Date</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Percentage</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Commission</th>
                                    <th scope="col"></th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                        </table>

                        @push('scripts')
                            <script>
                                $(function() {
                                    $('#users-table').DataTable({
                                        processing: true,
                                        serverSide: true,
                                        ajax: "{{ route('datatables.data') }}",


                                        columns: [{
                                                data: 'order.id',
                                                name: 'order'
                                            },
                                            {
                                                data: 'user.first_name',
                                                name: 'user.first_name'
                                            },
                                            {
                                                data: 'referrer.first_name',
                                                name: 'referrer.first_name'
                                            },
                                            {
                                                data: 'referred_distributors',
                                                name: 'referred_distributors'
                                            },
                                            {
                                                data: 'order.order_date',
                                                name: 'order.order_date'
                                            },

                                            {
                                                data: 'percentage',
                                                name: 'percentage'
                                            },
                                            {
                                                data: 'commision',
                                                name: 'commision'
                                            },

                                        ]
                                    });
                                });
                            </script>
                        @endpush
```

if I eventually get the data to display on the table this is now brings me to my second question how do filter with the date inputs when the filter button is clicked.

Thanks

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74372421/how-to-update-table-using-date-range-in-laravel-and-ajax), which was asked about 10 minutes before yours.

Comment: I asked both questions just recovered this account believed I will get faster replies here deleting from the other account now, please help if you can

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using dataTables.

https://datatables.net/

Or even better yet, use laravel datatables: https://datatables.yajrabox.com/

I have also been working on a library that simplifies range filtering: https://laraveltesting.itulbuild.com/documentation/slickFilters
**(still a work in progress)**

Everything you need to know about how to handle range filtering on columns is outlined in the documentation for slickFilter.js above (even if you don't use the library).

----- EDIT ----

I noticed your javascript column definitions look incorrect.

This is probably closer to what you want

```
columns: [{
        data: 'invoice',
        name: 'order.id'
    },
    {
        data: 'purchaser',
        name: 'user.first_name'
    },
    {
        data: 'distributer',
        name: 'referrer.first_name'
    },
    {
        data: 'referred_distributors',
        name: 'referred_distributors'
    },
    {
        data: 'order_date',
        name: 'order.order_date'
    },

    {
        data: 'percentage',
        name: 'percentage'
    },
    {
        data: 'commision',
        name: 'commision'
    },
    {
        data: 'action',
        filterable: false,
        sortable: false
    }
]
```

Comment: Thank you for suggesting Datatables as an alternative, I have the data which I need in the browser, which i confirmed from the network tab of my browser inspector , in an array 10 of them seeing from the responses and preview of the network tab, what I need now is how to display them on the datatable because it keeps coming out empty, if i return the datatable inside the foreach loop it returns and shows only one result. @dvicemuse I will be updating my original code with the new one please help

Comment: i have just updated my initial question and code

Comment: when using datatables, it paginates for you... so you dont want to "prepaginate" your orders. change `$orders = Order::simplePaginate(10);` to `$orders = Order::all()` and see if it renders correctly.